Problem with wifi connection after upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04
I've been struggling for the past 2 weeks with this problem, after upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04.
At first, I was able to access some sites but not others. Following some answers on this websites, I mingled with DNS and Network configurations. This led to other problems and other fixes I do not fully remember.
Here is the current state:

When starting my computer, it detects no wifi. Here is the status:
$ sudo systemctl status NetworkManager



NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-12-08 11:01:43 CET; 10min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 1266 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 3868)
     Memory: 18.6M (peak: 33.9M)
        CPU: 785ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─1266 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

    déc. 08 11:02:06 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[1266]: <warn>  [1733652126.4995] device (wlp2s0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#2).
    déc. 08 11:02:06 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[1266]: <error> [1733652126.5254] device (wlp2s0): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: GDBus.Error:fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.UnknownError: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
    déc. 08 11:02:13 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[1266]: <info>  [1733652133.5990] agent-manager: agent[85b7621e4b365fa6,:1.114/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
    déc. 08 11:02:16 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[1266]: <warn>  [1733652136.4952] device (wlp2s0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#3).
    déc. 08 11:02:16 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[1266]: <error> [1733652136.5456] device (wlp2s0): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: GDBus.Error:fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.UnknownError: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
    déc. 08 11:02:26 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[1266]: <warn>  [1733652146.5047] device (wlp2s0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#4).
    déc. 08 11:02:26 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[1266]: <error> [1733652146.5386] device (wlp2s0): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: GDBus.Error:fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.UnknownError: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
    déc. 08 11:02:36 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[1266]: <warn>  [1733652156.4968] device (wlp2s0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#5).
    déc. 08 11:02:36 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[1266]: <error> [1733652156.5205] device (wlp2s0): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: GDBus.Error:fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.UnknownError: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
    déc. 08 11:02:36 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[1266]: <info>  [1733652156.5205] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface keeps failing, giving up

    $ sudo systemctl status wpa_supplicant

    wpa_supplicant.service - WPA supplicant
         Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service; disabled; preset: enabled)
         Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-12-08 11:01:43 CET; 12min ago
       Main PID: 1610 (wpa_supplicant)
          Tasks: 1 (limit: 3868)
         Memory: 1.7M (peak: 2.2M)
            CPU: 53ms
         CGroup: /system.slice/wpa_supplicant.service
                 └─1610 /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O "DIR=/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev"
    déc. 08 11:02:36 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[1610]: nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
    déc. 08 11:02:36 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[1610]: nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
    déc. 08 11:02:36 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[1610]: nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
    déc. 08 11:02:36 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[1610]: nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
    déc. 08 11:02:36 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[1610]: ctrl_iface exists and seems to be in use - cannot override it
    déc. 08 11:02:36 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[1610]: Delete '/run/wpa_supplicant/wlp2s0' manually if it is not used anymore
    déc. 08 11:02:36 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[1610]: Failed to initialize control interface 'DIR=/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev'.
                                                                  You may have another wpa_supplicant process already running or the file was
                                                                  left by an unclean termination of wpa_supplicant in which case you will need
                                                                  to manually remove this file before starting wpa_supplicant again.
    déc. 08 11:02:36 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[1610]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
    déc. 08 11:02:36 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[1610]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
    déc. 08 11:02:36 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[1610]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0


I then restart my wifi using
sudo systemctl stop wpa_supplicant
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager


Usually networks are detected, but the wifi keeps reconnecting, most often it fails and shows the Ubuntu message « Connection failed ; Activation of network connection failed » ; but sometimes the connection succeeds and I receive some notifications and messages.
Here is the status:
   $ sudo systemctl status NetworkManager  

 NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-12-08 11:15:38 CET; 54s ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 5232 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 3868)
     Memory: 4.8M (peak: 20.4M)
        CPU: 617ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─5232 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
déc. 08 11:16:11 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[5232]: <info>  [1733652971.9995] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
déc. 08 11:16:22 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[5232]: <info>  [1733652982.0016] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
déc. 08 11:16:22 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[5232]: <info>  [1733652982.0016] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
déc. 08 11:16:26 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[5232]: <info>  [1733652986.4345] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
déc. 08 11:16:26 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[5232]: <info>  [1733652986.4345] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
déc. 08 11:16:32 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[5232]: <warn>  [1733652992.4978] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
déc. 08 11:16:32 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[5232]: <info>  [1733652992.4979] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
déc. 08 11:16:32 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[5232]: <info>  [1733652992.4992] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
déc. 08 11:16:32 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[5232]: <warn>  [1733652992.5002] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'carbowifi-5G-stop'
déc. 08 11:16:32 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[5232]: <info>  [1733652992.5009] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

 $ sudo systemctl status wpa_supplicant 

wpa_supplicant.service - WPA supplicant
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service; disabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-12-08 11:15:38 CET; 1min 0s ago
   Main PID: 5398 (wpa_supplicant)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 3868)
     Memory: 1.6M (peak: 2.1M)
        CPU: 97ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/wpa_supplicant.service
             └─5398 /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O "DIR=/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev"
déc. 08 11:16:26 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[5398]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="carbowifi-5G-stop"
déc. 08 11:16:26 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[5398]: wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with b4:b0:24:b9:bb:be (SSID='carbowifi-5G-stop' freq=5240 MHz)
déc. 08 11:16:26 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[5398]: wlp2s0: SME: Authentication request to the driver failed
déc. 08 11:16:26 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[5398]: BSSID b4:b0:24:b9:bb:be ignore list count incremented to 2, ignoring for 10 seconds
déc. 08 11:16:26 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[5398]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="carbowifi-5G-stop" auth_failures=2 duration=20 reason=CONN_FAILED
déc. 08 11:16:33 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[5398]: wlp2s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
déc. 08 11:16:37 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[5398]: wlp2s0: WPS-CANCEL
déc. 08 11:16:37 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[5398]: wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with b4:b0:24:b9:bb:be (SSID='carbowifi-5G-stop' freq=5240 MHz)
déc. 08 11:16:37 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[5398]: wlp2s0: SME: Authentication request to the driver failed
déc. 08 11:16:37 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[5398]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="carbowifi-5G-stop" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED here

After some time, weirdly, the wifi gets stable and says it is connected:

      $ sudo systemctl status NetworkManager  

    NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
         Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
         Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-12-08 11:15:38 CET; 17min ago
           Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
       Main PID: 5232 (NetworkManager)
          Tasks: 4 (limit: 3868)
         Memory: 4.7M (peak: 20.4M swap: 2.2M swap peak: 2.3M)
            CPU: 5.620s
         CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
                 └─5232 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
    déc. 08 11:33:35 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[5232]: <info>  [1733654015.5075] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
    déc. 08 11:33:35 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[5232]: <info>  [1733654015.5254] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
    déc. 08 11:33:35 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[5232]: <info>  [1733654015.5258] device (wlp2s0): ip:dhcp4: restarting
    déc. 08 11:33:35 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[5232]: <info>  [1733654015.5358] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
    déc. 08 11:33:35 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[5232]: <info>  [1733654015.5358] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
    déc. 08 11:33:35 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[5232]: <info>  [1733654015.5358] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed no lease
    déc. 08 11:33:35 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[5232]: <info>  [1733654015.5359] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
    déc. 08 11:33:35 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[5232]: <info>  [1733654015.5361] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
    déc. 08 11:33:35 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[5232]: <info>  [1733654015.6944] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.27, acd pending
    déc. 08 11:33:35 philax-Aspire-S3-392G NetworkManager[5232]: <info>  [1733654015.6947] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.27
    
       $ sudo systemctl status wpa_supplicant  

    wpa_supplicant.service - WPA supplicant
         Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service; disabled; preset: enabled)
         Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-12-08 11:15:38 CET; 18min ago
       Main PID: 5398 (wpa_supplicant)
          Tasks: 1 (limit: 3868)
         Memory: 1.2M (peak: 2.3M swap: 1008.0K swap peak: 1020.0K)
            CPU: 1.754s
         CGroup: /system.slice/wpa_supplicant.service
                 └─5398 /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O "DIR=/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev"
    déc. 08 11:33:35 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[5398]: wlp2s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with b4:b0:24:b9:bb:bf [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
    déc. 08 11:33:35 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[5398]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to b4:b0:24:b9:bb:bf completed [id=0 id_str=]
    déc. 08 11:33:35 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[5398]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-67 noise=9999 txrate=0
    déc. 08 11:33:40 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[5398]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=b4:b0:24:b9:bb:bf reason=1 locally_generated=1
    déc. 08 11:33:40 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[5398]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
    déc. 08 11:33:40 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[5398]: wlp2s0: No network configuration found for the current AP
    déc. 08 11:33:40 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[5398]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=b4:b0:24:b9:bb:be reason=3 locally_generated=1
    déc. 08 11:33:40 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[5398]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
    déc. 08 11:33:40 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[5398]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
    déc. 08 11:33:40 philax-Aspire-S3-392G wpa_supplicant[5398]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=DE

Though the wifi is then very slow, and it feels like some sites don't work:
--- google.com ping statistics ---
69 packets transmitted, 32 received, 53.6232% packet loss, time 68810ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.272/43.283/144.060/38.257 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
41 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 40971ms
From 192.168.0.1 icmp_seq=5 Destination Net Unreachable

--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 9 received, 0% packet loss, time 8008ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.432/58.732/125.008/42.910 ms

I have to admit I am very lost and starting to loose my nerves... Please do ask if you need more info ! Thank you very much
More info about my setup:
    $ sudo ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 30  bytes 3055 (3.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 30  bytes 3055 (3.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.225  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::8286:f2ff:fe73:d4a8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fd00::1:8286:f2ff:fe73:d4a8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2a01:cb08:b64:2900:8286:f2ff:fe73:d4a8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 80:86:f2:73:d4:a8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 122188  bytes 177573076 (177.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 48  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17189  bytes 2516154 (2.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    $ lspci -knn | grep -i wireless
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 73)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-N 7260 [Wilkins Peak 2] [8086:4060]

    $ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=systemd-resolved

[ifupdown]
managed=true

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

